# anychart ganttResource how to change range/zoom on the fly

Tags: anychart

I use anychart.ganttResource ()
Currently, I limit the timeline of my data by setting a range outside of Gantt, which controls the period I get data from - and I have chart.zoomTo ("week", 2, "firstDate"). This works fine, but now my client want to be able to "zoom" in the chart.
I can see that this is possible using maps, but I can not find anything similar in Gantt. Ideally I would like a slider which could control the zoom or something like zoomOnMouseWheel, but I don't know if this is posible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Zooming with mouseWheel events is possible with some code tricks. I have prepared an example for you, please check it.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function (){

  // data tree settings
  var treeData = anychart.data.tree(data, "as-table");

  // chart type
  var chart = anychart.ganttResource();

  // chart position
  chart.bounds(0, 0, "100%", "100%");

  // chart data
  chart.data(treeData);

  // data tree width
  chart.splitterPosition(170);

  var dataGrid = chart.dataGrid();

  // settings for first column
  dataGrid.column(0).width(30).title().text("#");

  // settings for the second column
  dataGrid.column(1).width(140).format(function(item) {
    return item.get("name");
  }).title().text("Person");

  
  // chart container
  chart.container("container").draw();
  
  //zooming feature
  var zoomingCoef = 1;
  var isPreviousNegative = true;
  
  //mouse wheel listener
   $("#container").on('wheel', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     
     //define the zoomingCoef
     if(e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0 ^ isPreviousNegative) {
      zoomingCoef -= e.originalEvent.deltaY/10;
     } else {
      zoomingCoef =1;
     }
   
     //zoomIn or zoomOut
     if(e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
      chart.zoomIn(zoomingCoef);
       isPreviousNegative = true;
     } else {
      chart.zoomOut(zoomingCoef);
       isPreviousNegative = false;
     }
});
});

// data
var data = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Phase 1 - Strategic Plan",
    "periods": [
      {"id": "1_1", "start": 1171468800000, "end": 1171987200000, "fill": "green"}]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Self-Assessment",
    "periods": [
      {"id": "2_1", "start": 1173024000000, "end": 1173715200000, "fill": "yellow"}]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Define business vision",
    "periods": [
      {"id": "3_1", "start": 1169740800000, "end": 1170172800000, "fill": "green"}]
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Identify available skills, information and support",
    "periods": [
      {"id": "4_1", "start": 1171814400000, "end": 1172419200000, "fill": "green"}]
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Decide whether to proceed",
    "periods": [
      {"id": "5_1", "start": 1171296000000, "end": 1171382400000, "fill": "green"}]
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Define the Opportunity",
    "periods": [
      {"id": "6_1", "start": 1173628800000, "end": 1174320000000, "fill": "green"}]
  }
];
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/css/anychart-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing in the zoomIn/zoomOut part. When I'm zooming it's like the zoom out is delayed, I continue to zoom in when I change the "direction" on the mouse wheel and then suddently I start zooming out. If you first zoom in 4 times and then zoom out 4 times you don't end where you started

Comment: I have investigated this a bit further, and it seems as if the zoomingCoef is behaving a bit odd.
This may be due to deltaY being browser depending, in Crome it's 100 and in Firefox it's 3
So if I zoom in and out 5 times in Crome zoomingCoef will be
11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 1, -9, -19, -29, -39
while doing the same in Firefox will give
1.3, 1.6, 1.9000000000000001, 2.2, 2.5, 1, 0.7, 0.39999999999999997, 0.09999999999999998, -0.2
So I need to zoom out more in Firefox before zoomingCoef will be negative and hence actually zoom out.

Comment: yes, this is a cross-browser solution to suit Firefox restrictions related to mouse wheel events. Also, the line 45 in the snippet above better to replace to zoomingCoef =e.originalEvent.deltaY/10; This will provide zooming instantly after changing the direction of zooming.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't help me. The zoom in Firefox is still acting weird. I think it due to zoomingCoef being in the interval between -1 and 1. Please explain why you are using e.originalEvent.deltaY/10; I cannot figure out how this can work when deltaY < 10

Comment: the divider is equal 10 to reduce (to make smooth) the speed of zooming in many browsers. Rotating the mouse wheel with high speed brings very high numbers of e.originalEvent.deltaY and you will zoom to the max or min instantly. You are free to adjust the divider for your purpose or even define different dividers for different browsers to avoid the difference in behavior.

Comment: Sorry for all the newbee questions, but is there any difference on chart.zoomOut(2); and chart.zoomOut(-2); ? My first impression was that zoomOut need a negative number and zoomIn a positive number, is this correct?

Comment: zoomOut and zoomIn take Math.abs() from the argument. So there's no difference between -2 and 2. So, in the snippet, it takes the deltaY right from the event context. If the deltaY is negative then use zoomIn() otherwise zoomOut()

Comment: I just saw the Interactive stock chart example (https://jsfiddle.net/q7vobxjw/2/), and finds the way you control the timeline very elegant. Can the same be done in a ganttResource tree?

Comment: Gantt and Stocks charts have some differences in API, so you can achieve the same in Gantt with some other methods, you can check the example here - https://playground.anychart.com/DME6eMJ3